# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component [React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Getting this error:

react_devtools_backend.js:4049 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Connect(HeaderComponent)`) while rendering a different component (`MyApp`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MyApp`, follow the stack trace.

My code :

```
const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    
    getSignInInfo();

  },[]);

const getSignInInfo = async () => {
    const isAuth = await localStorage.getItem("OAUTH_RES");
    setFirstRender( true );
    setIsAuth( isAuth );
  };
```

The problem is in this code. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you post your original component. ?

Comment: Please, provide a code of `MyApp` component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.